# How to write unit test for http request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to do an unit test a service in my case

In my test controller

```
myService.getItem('/api/toy/' + scope.id).success(
   function(toy) {
       $scope.toy = toys.details;
   }
);
```

MyService

```
angular.module('toyApp').service('myService', ['$http',
    function($http) {
        var service = {};
        return {
            getItem: function(url) {
                return $http.get(url);
            },
        };
    }
]);
```

Test file.

```
describe('toy ctrl', function () {
    var $httpBackend, ctrl, myService;

    beforeEach(module('toyApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_, __myService_) {
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        myService = _myService_;

        ctrl = _$controller_('toyCtrl', {
            $scope: scope
        });      

    }));

    describe('call my service', function() {
        it('should make request when app loads', function() {
            $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/toy/123').respond({id:123, detail:456 });
            myService.getItem('/api/toy/123').then(function(toy){
                expect(scope.toy.detail).toBe(456);
            })
            $httpBackend.flush();   
     })
 })
```

I am getting

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/toy/123
No more request expected
```

If I take out `$httpBackend.flush()`, the error is gone but it won't cover the

```
  function(toy) {
       $scope.toy = toys.details;
   }
```

part. I want to cover the function call and not sure how to do this. Can anyone help me about it? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you unit testing controller or service (should make request when app loads seems like controller)?

Comment: I am testing service inside my controller

Comment: Ok. in that case you could just mock your service out and inject it to the controller. And test value against scope. Basically what i am trying to say is when you unit test controller you just have to test the controller logic `myService.getItem('/api/toy/123')` is irrelevant actually.

Comment: @PSL could you please provide an example? +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are "unit" testing the controller, so you don't have to bring in the service in picture as you just need to test the controller logic. You could create a mock service and inject it while creating the controller in your test.

Example:

```
var mockItem = {details:{//somestuff}, id:'1'};// set up a mock object to test against later
//....
beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_, _$q_) {
    scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

    //Set up mock
    myService = jasmine.CreateSpyObj('myService', ['getItem']); 
    myService.getItem.and.returnValue($q.when(mockItem ));

    ctrl = _$controller_('toyCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        myService: myService //<-- Pass it here
    });      

}));


  //.....Assuming you are making the call when controller is instantiated
  it('should make request when app loads', function() {
     expect(myService.getItem).toHaveBeenCalled();
     //You could also check as below
     //expect(myService.getItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedidpassedin);
     scope.$digest(); //Resolve $q promise callback
     expect($scope.toy).toEqual(mockItem .details);
  });
```

If you are specifically unit testing your service alone you could do:

```
it('should make request when app loads', function() {
        var resp;
        $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/toy/123').respond({id:123, detail:456});
        myService.getItem('/api/toy/123').then(function(response){
            resp = response.data;
        });
        $httpBackend.flush();   
        expect(resp.detail).toEqual(456);
 });
```

In your controller instead of chaining `success` use `then`

```
 myService.getItem('/api/toy/' + scope.id).then(
   function(response) {
       $scope.toy = response.toys.details;
   });
```

Comment: Thanks I am getting error when use .then, it seems like it can't find the response if I use then. +1

Comment: @FlyingCat That should not be an issue. then is a part of q promise. success is part of http promise which is just a wrapper over q promise. Then should just be available everywhere. Also make sure you do `$q.when(data)` in your test. Also note that when you use `then` `response.data` is response that you get a first argument in `success` callback